# Add "update available, please refresh" prompt to PWABuilder Cache-first service worker

Tags: javascript, service-worker, progressive-web-apps, user-experience, pwabuilder

I'm making my website offline first with service worker. I want to prompt user to refresh the page when updated content is available. I want users to know that they are viewing outdated contend, so they can get latest content by refreshing the page.

These implementations are a good example:

1. [Service worker demo by Mozilla](https://serviceworke.rs/strategy-cache-update-and-refresh_demo.html)
2. Approach #3 in [this article](https://redfin.engineering/how-to-fix-the-refresh-button-when-using-service-workers-a8e27af6df68).

I am using cache-first service worker provided by PWABuilder. It works well, but it does not prompt the user of available updates.

I have tried to copy the code from the articles above, but couldn't get it to work.

[Here is the repo of the service worker I currently use.](https://github.com/pwa-builder/pwabuilder-serviceworkers/tree/master/serviceWorker4)

The code I am trying to add to the service worker script:

```
addEventListener('message', messageEvent => {
  if (messageEvent.data === 'skipWaiting') return skipWaiting();
});
```

Script I'm trying to add to the webpage:

```
/ reload once when the new Service Worker starts activating
var refreshing;
navigator.serviceWorker.addEventListener('controllerchange',
  function() {
    if (refreshing) return;
    refreshing = true;
    window.location.reload();
  }
);
function promptUserToRefresh(reg) {
  // this is just an example
  // don't use window.confirm in real life; it's terrible
  if (window.confirm("New version available! OK to refresh?")) {
    reg.waiting.postMessage('skipWaiting');
  }
}
listenForWaitingServiceWorker(reg, promptUserToRefresh);
```

If I just add this code to service worker and webpage respectfully, the service worker functions fine. But update prompt does not work.

I get this error in console:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: reg is not defined
    at (index):231
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, your problem doesn't necessarily have that much to do with Service Workers :) If you look at the error message (shown in console) carefully, you'll see that it is clearly telling you *a variable called reg is not defined*. In other words, somewhere in your code you're trying to reference a variable with a name "reg" but "reg" doesn't exist there.

It seems that the code pasted in your question is not the whole thing, but I suspect the problem lies here:

```
listenForWaitingServiceWorker(reg, promptUserToRefresh);
```

Anyhow, the error message tells you the problem occurs at line 231 in your html file so check that out.

Comment: Thanks. I don't know javascript well enough to fix it my self. I managed to create PWA capable static site with hugo following tutorials, but I cant really code. Hope I can get some help here.